# Python timer for timing

Tags: python, timer, while-loop

This program asks the user questions, but only gives him/her 10 seconds to answer each one. If they answer the question within the time limit, the program move on to the next question at that instant. Also, if they don't answer within the time limit, the program will skip onto the next question after 10 seconds. I know about the timer class, how can I integrate it to do this? Here is my code I have so far. Don't worry about the pmXXXXX stuff, it's a software I'm using for school project.

```
    #question1
one = raw_input("Question 1:" + "\n" + qa + "\n" + "x" + "\n" + "A. Brightens it" + "\n" + "B. A gradient of black to white." + "\n" + "C. A color pallete.")
if(one.lower() == "b"):
    print "Congrats! 10 points."
        pmNewComputedImage("Question 1 Answer", 256, 256, "x")
        score += 10
else:
        print "Wrong. -10 points. Here's the answer."
        window1 = pmNewComputedImage("Question 1 Answer", 256, 256, "x")
        score -= 10



#question2
pmNewComputedImage("Question 2", 256, 256, "x*2")
two = raw_input("Question 2:" + "\n" + qb + "\n" + "A. x/2" + "\n" + "B. y/2" + "\n" + "C. x*2")
if (two.lower() == "c"):
    print "Congrats! 10 points."
    score += 10
else:
    print "Wrong -10 points. The answer is C."
    score -= 10


def stopwatch(seconds):
    import time
    start = time.time()
    time.clock()
    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < seconds:
                elapsed = time.time() - start
                print "Seconds count: %02d" % elapsed
                time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If the user takes too long, do you want to interrupt him, abandon the prompt and whatever he'd already typed, etc.? Or wait for him anyway, and then tell him he took too long? If the former, does this need to be cross-platform? If not, what platform do you need it for?

Comment: I was think if 10 seconds is reached, then close the existing question window and show another window saying "out of time," then on to the next question. I'm not clear, what do you mean by platform?

Comment: What window? You're using `raw_input`, which just asks for input on the current stdin. If you're running inside the IDLE development environment (which none of your real users will be), this involve a popup, but normally it will be a readline-enabled prompt on the command line.

Comment: For "platform": Mac, Windows, Linux, etc. But ideally, as specific as possible: Windows 8.1 64-bit with official-installer 64-bit Python 2.7.4, or OS X 10.9.3 with a Homebrew-installed Python 2.7, or Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 with the default Python 2.6.8, or whatever.

Comment: Just a side note. Rather than using `+` between a lot of small strings in your input prompts you could do a prompt as a single string, like this: `"Question 1:\n%s\nx\nA. Brightens it\nB. A gradient of black to white.\nC. A color palette." % qa`. And then you could collect all the prompt strings into a neat tuple or list. Also, `if(one.lower() == "b"):` would be better as `if one.upper() == "B"):` since you're using upper case in the prompt.

Comment: Thanks PM 2Ring for the tip. This just made things a lot simpler.

Comment: @abarnert: This is for a school project, we're actually just running the code inside of PixelMath, a university software. It's the same as running it inside of IDLE, but with all the pmXXXX functions. So I guess the pop up windows must be had.

Comment: @user3211857: OK, does PixelMath have any way for you to write actual GUI programs? Because this is a _great_ opportunity to learn the basics of event-loop-based programming and how it's different from linear command-line-style apps. And if that's coming later in the class, you probably want to either skip ahead, or just wait for that part of the class, instead of trying to learn how to use background threads and Unix-style signals on Windows and so on, just for this project.

Answer (score 1):

The `raw_input` function just isn't going to return until the user types something, so you can't directly do this.

There are multiple ways around it. You can run the timer in a background thread and use signals to interrupt the main thread; you can just use `signal.alarm` to do it automatically without even needing a background thread (but not on Windows); you can put `sys.stdin` in nonblocking mode and use lower-level I/O to read instead of `raw_input`; you can do the input in a child process and terminate it if it takes too long, etc.

Here's an example of the first version which may even work on Windows, although I won't promise that it will in practice:

```
import os
import signal
import threading

try:
    mysig = signal.CTRL_C_EVENT
except NameError:
    mysig = signal.SIGINT

def timed_raw_input(prompt, timeout):
    t = threading.Timer(timeout, lambda: os.kill(os.getpid(), mysig))
    try:
        t.start()
        result = raw_input(prompt)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return '' # or whatever you want to do on timeout
    else:
        t.cancel()
        return result
```

I'm not sure if `CTRL_C_EVENT` really does raise `KeyboardInterrupt` on Windows; you may have to install your own handler with [`signal.signal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal). Read the linked docs, and test it yourself and see. If you have to install a signal handler, you might as well use one of the other available cross-platform signals instead of `CTRL_C_EVENT`, and raise your own custom exception instead of `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: Nice one, i am on a windows machine, it won't interrupt, even with stdin (i replaced raw_input with stdin() ) it gonna stay uninterrupted. i just called timed_raw_input("whats x?", 3.0)

Comment: @user1767754: OK, so tru writing your own handler using `signal.signal`, raising a custom exception, possibly using one of the Windows-compatible signal names mentioned in the docs instead of `CTRL_C_EVENT`.

Comment: @user1767754: However, if you're running this in IDLE, it's worth mentioning that IDLE does funky things to signal handling, and any actual users will not be running in IDLE, so that may not be the best way to test things. (If you want a GUI, a better solution would be to build a simple Tkinter GUI, which should take not much more code than building an alerting timer, and will have a lot of other advantages—like showing the results in a window instead of an output log.)

Comment: "what do you mean by platform" is code for "I'm using Windows". :) Yeah, this is _definitely_ a job for a GUI.

Comment: @PM2Ring: That used to be true a few years ago, but nowadays it can also mean "I'm using a Mac". :)

Comment: :). OTOH, since it's for Windows only, I guess it could be done fairly easily in the console using [msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch()](http://effbot.org/librarybook/msvcrt.htm) to get the input. But I guess a GUI would look nicer & more professional.

Comment: @PM2Ring: But there's still no way to block until a key or for X seconds, and you don't want to spin on `kbhit()`, not to mention that you get no editing that way unless you implement it manually (which is going to be a lot less user-friendly than the usual `readline` or native Windows line-editing support…), and you'll be explicitly breaking IDLE instead of being just a bit less nice…

Comment: True, although spinning on kbhit() is a common technique. :) From the code above, the responses are single letters, and the user only has 10 seconds to respond, so I don't think we need to provide editing capability. I haven't used IDLE much, so I can't comment on that issue, but we don't actually know that the OP is using IDLE...

Comment: @PM2Ring: Spinning on `kbhit` is a horrible technique, and should not be taught to innocent novices. Editing is still useful for single-character inputs if you want to allow people to correct typos instead of insta-failing them (unless you're going to add a Regis "is that your final answer?" prompt). And I'm pretty sure the OP is using IDLE, or some other IDE that does something similar, because he talks about `input` opening a window—but whatever he's doing, if there's a window involved, `khbit` probably won't work.

Comment: Yeah, ok. My smilie above was to indicate that using kbhit() is a bit of a MS tradition, not that I actually approve of it. :) I totally agree that it's horrible, and in ancient times, when I was programming in C on the Amiga, I heartily denounced many DOS  programmers for doing it, both because it's a resource hog and it's unportable. But I shall refrain from mentioning it to newbies here in future.

Comment: @PM2Ring: On a 286 DOS machine it really wasn't so bad, because you were only running one program at a time, your CPU used the same amount of electricity whether it was at 100% or 20%, and the other alternatives provided by DOS just sucked bad. It was still a bad habit that took people and communities a long time to unlearn, but it only became a bad habit because it wasn't really harmful in its original context…